# Are there any restrictions on the event 'onDeviceMotion' on iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, iphone, events

I am having an issue accessing the onDeviceMotion event on iOS. It works on Android.

I was following a tutorial and the code works perfectly fine on my iOS device, but when I copy/paste the exact same code and run it from my localhost on my iOS device, the onDeviceMotion event is not triggered. **The same code runs just fine on my Android device on Chrome and Firefox.** So instead of it being a code issue, I'm thinking it's an Apple restriction.

I am on iOS 12 and have the motion sensor on Safari enabled.

Are there any restrictions that I should be aware of for motion events on iOS? Such as necessary https or CORS? My server is written in Node.JS.

Below is the code that I'm talking about.

```
window.addEventListener('devicemotion', onDeviceMotion, true);

function onDeviceMotion(event) {
    let x = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.x;
    let y = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.y;
    let z = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.z;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that Safari will restrict some events, especially motion events, from running on unsecure websites over HTTP. You must set up and enable HTTPS and the events will then be triggered.

**Node.JS**

```
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync( 'keys/server.key' );
const certificate = fs.readFileSync( 'keys/server.crt' );
https.createServer({
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate
}, app).listen(8080);
```